# Get Page and Count the rows in a html table using php

Tags: php, html, dom

help me with the code

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('index.html');
foreach($homepage->find('table') as $table){ 
     // returns all the <tr> tag inside $table
     $all_trs = $table->find('tr');
     $count = count($all_trs);
     echo $count;
}
```

i am trying to get content of index.html and then count the number of tr tags but the above code isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what context this code is in, but you can use `file_get_contents()` and `substr_count()` to do what you want.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

```
echo substr_count(strtolower(file_get_contents('index.html')), '<tr>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DOM](http://www.php.net/dom) API for this purpose:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile('index.html');
$tr_count = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tr')->length;
```